# OpenGL Separating RGB channels

Tags: c++, opengl-es, textures

using OpenGL, I have uploaded my image into a texture:

```
glTexImage2D (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, imageWidth, imageHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
```

Now, I want to see whether I can separate my channels with the help of OpenGL?
For example, to be able to store my Red/Green/Blue Channels each in a separate buffer?
Is this something easy to do with OpenGL?

Comment: You can access channels separately, and also draw it into single channeled buffers. However from the way you ask your question I have the impression you mistake OpenGL for some general purpose image manipulation library. OpenGL's primary objective is drawing nice pictures to the screen. Image processing is a nice byproduct of this.

Comment: @datenwolf: Well I am planning on doing some image processing, but the whole idea is that doing image processing with GPU would be lot faster than CPU. If you don't believe this would be the case, then I would not spend too much time trying to do it this way? please advise!

Comment: It depends on what you actually plan to do. GPUs are made for image processing, so using the GPU is not a bad idea on itself. But using a dedicated GPGPU API like OpenCL (note the 'C') may be better suited for your purposes.

Comment: @datenwolf: I would like to multiply images together. For example, I have two images of size 320x240 each, and I would like to use Shaders to multiply these two images, and read it back to memory, and I can do more stuff with it.

Comment: The "read back" part is, what really pushes this application toward OpenCL. With OpenCL you can write it directly to some buffer that can be mapped into your client process' address space. With OpenGL you'd have to prepare an FBO, setup texture objects, setup a VBO to draw a quad, using those two images as textures, you need a vertex shader as well to position the quad, etc. etc. Using OpenCL for such things is much more straightforward.

Comment: @datenwolf: Unfortunately, the hardware platform that I am running the application on, only accepts OpenGL or OpenVG. So, considering the complications that are involved in OpenGL, and considering that the only interfaces available are OpenGL/OpenVG, do you think that I would still buy some speed performance with OpenGL compared to do everything in CPU? If the answer is yes, then I am willing to invest time doing it with OpenGL, but do it the right way! But if I would not gain any advantage at all, then I would just stay away from OpenGL and would just use CPU (CPU is not that strong either)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25560/discussion-between-user2112840-and-datenwolf)

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenGL RGBA pixel data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169799/opengl-rgba-pixel-data)

Comment: When it comes to image processing a GPU will always outperform a CPU by several orders of magnitude. I was not suggesting the the GPU was a poor choice, but that OpenGL as an API might not be the right thing. But if it's the only thing available to you, then use it.

Answer (score 2):

`RGB` texture can be looked at as 3 separate buffers, but saved in memory with stride. If you however need to use three separate contiguous buffers, there's `GL_RED` format, which you could use three times, each time for one channel.

To draw from this kind of data, you would have to either put data back into one buffer, or use a shader that would sample from 3 textures at once:

```
vec2 tc;
sampler2d red, green, blue;

my_out_color = vec4(texture(red, tc).r, texture(green, tc).r, texture(blue, tc).r, 1.0);
```